# What are $f, g$ such that $f(x^y) = g(x, f(y))$?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, functional-equations

For example, $\ln(x^y) = \ln(x) \times y$, so $\ln$, so to speak, *"distributes"* into the first argument of exponentiation, while turning it into multiplication.

I wonder if there is a function that *"distributes"* into the second argument of exponentiation, but I have no idea how to even approach the search.

**P.S.**   There are of course some trivial solutions, like for example $f(x) = x$. Of interest though are those that do not involve computing $x^y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x^y) = g(x, f(y))$$

Substitute $y=f^{-1}(v)$. Then $$f(x^{f^{-1}(v)})=g(x,v)$$ and so we have a general formula for $g$.

Therefore the perhaps surprising answer is that all functions $f$ can be said to satisfy an equation of this form.

For any function $f$, simply define $g$ by
$$g(u,v)=f(u^{f^{-1}(v)}).$$

For example, if $f$ is the doubling function then 
$$g(u,v)=2(u^{\frac{v}{2}}).$$

You can use this to explore what happens for different $f$. The real issue is perhaps whether one can find a function $f$ which gives a "nice" function $g$ as happened in your opening example.

Comment: “Sherlock Holmes and Dr. Watson went on a hot air balloon ride. A storm took the balloon above the clouds, and after a few days brought it down close to the ground. Below a man was herding sheep.

– “Where are we?” – Dr. Watson cried to him.
– The man looked at them and replied – “You are in a hot air balloon.”

— [Source.](http://www.deadprogrammer.com/tag/dr-watson)

Comment: If you can show that this class of solutions is exhaustive, I will be sure to accept the answer.

Comment: It is exhaustive - I'll amend the answer to show this.

Comment: I must need to meditate on this for some while. A minor nitpick though is that the substitution $y = f^{-1}(v)$ requires that $f^{-1}$ exists, so this derivation only works for invertible functions.

Comment: Agreed - but most functions I expect you might want to use here will be invertible at least on some domains.